# Segmentation fault when getting host information

Tags: c, network-programming

It happens when called at high concurrency,it seems the result of `gethostbyname` is not cached ?

```
static int proxy_getaddr(char *HostName)
{
    struct hostent*     Host;
    Host=gethostbyname(HostName);

    if(!Host)
    {
        unsigned long int addr=inet_addr(HostName);
        if(addr!=-1)
            Host=gethostbyaddr((char*)addr,sizeof(addr),AF_INET);
    }
    ...
```

Here's the core dump:

```
0x00000034f40e98b1 in gethostbyaddr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0x000000000040182c in proxy_getaddr (HostName=0x48d75be0 "stackoverflow.com")
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of gethostbyaddr is supposed to be a pointer to an in_addr structure, not a pointer to a long. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect.  You are passing the result of `inet_addr()`, cast to a pointer, but what you actually want is the *address* of this:

```
Host = gethostbyaddr(&addr, sizeof(addr), AF_INET);
```

(The other comments, that you should be using `in_addr_t` instead of `unsigned long int` are correct too, but it is unlikely that this specifically is causing your problem).

Comment: so `gethostbyaddr` can work with both `unsigned long int` and `in_addr_t` internally?

Comment: @DriverBoy: Not exactly, but `in_addr_t` is defined as being *"An unsigned integral type of exactly 32 bits.*", so as long as `unsigned long int` on your platform matches that description, it is likely to work.  You should still change it to `in_addr_t`, though.

Comment: seems it's not working,I'm having this trouble again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095026/whats-the-reason-of-this-segmentation-fault

Comment: @DriverBoy: JeremyP has the right answer there - `h_addr` is `NULL`.  By the way, there is no need for the fallback path calling `inet_addr()` and `gethostbyaddr()`, because `gethostbyname()` works fine if given an IP address rather than a hostname.

Comment: but why is `h_addr` equal to `NULL`?I've even run `nscd` to cache the name resolution result...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation found here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html), you are passing in the wrong values:

> `gethostbyaddr()` takes a struct `in_addr` or struct `in6_addr` and brings you up a corresponding host name (if there is one), so it's sort of the reverse of `gethostbyname()`. As for parameters, even though addr is a `char*`, you **actually want to pass in a pointer to a struct `in_addr`**. `len` should be `sizeof(struct in_addr)`, and type should be `AF_INET`.

Here is some example code from the quoted site:

```
struct hostent *he;
struct in_addr ipv4addr;
struct in6_addr ipv6addr;

inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.0.2.34", &ipv4addr);
he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof ipv4addr, AF_INET);
printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);

inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:63b3:1::beef", &ipv6addr);
he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv6addr, sizeof ipv6addr, AF_INET6);
printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);
```

Comment: It happens when called at high concurrency,it seems the result of `gethostbyname` is not cached ?