# What's the reason of this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, coredump

It doesn't happen always,but will happen when the server application has been running for quite a while.

What's the reason and how can I fix it?

Code as follows:

```
struct hostent*     Host;
Result->sin_family=AF_INET;
Result->sin_port=htons((unsigned short)Port);

Host=gethostbyname(HostName);

if(!Host)
{
    unsigned long int addr=inet_addr(HostName);
    if(addr!=-1)
        Host=gethostbyaddr(&addr,sizeof(addr),AF_INET);

    if(!Host)
    {
        if(errno!=ETIMEDOUT)
            errno=-1; /* use h_errno */
        printf("Unknown host for server [%s].", HostName);
        return(0);
    }
}

memcpy((char*)&Result->sin_addr,(char*)Host->h_addr,sizeof(Result->sin_addr));
```

core dump:

```
#0  0x0000000000401913 in proxy_getaddr (HostName=0x7ae30be0 "stackoverflow.com", Port=80, Result=0x7ae30bd0) at proxy.c:529

529     memcpy((char*)&Result->sin_addr,(char*)Host->h_addr,sizeof(Result->sin_addr));
(gdb) p *Host
$4 = {h_name = 0xc4ee048 "", h_aliases = 0xc4ee030, h_addrtype = 2, h_length = 4, h_addr_list = 0xc4ee038}
(gdb) print Result 
$5 = (struct sockaddr_in *) 0x7ae30bd0
(gdb) print *Result 
$6 = {sin_family = 2, sin_port = 20480, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}



(gdb) p Host->h_addr_list[0]
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) p Host->h_addr_list
$2 = (char **) 0x1bd9d050
```

Comment: Where is Result defined? It might be uninitialized.

Comment: What happens when you print Result and *Result there ?

Comment: @eyalm,@nos,updated with more info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault when getting host information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056482/segmentation-fault-when-getting-host-information) posted by same user.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth,I thought that answer was right,but seems not...

Answer (score 3):

Given that the Host and Result variables both point to legitimate blocks of memory, the most likely cause is that `Host->h_addr` is `NULL`.  This would be the case if the list of addresses returned by `gethostbyname()` or `gethostbyaddr()` were empty.

I don't know how that could be caused (the documentation on my OS X system implies that both functions should return NULL if no addresses can be found).  However, I would check `Host->h_addr_list[0]` in the debugger to confirm.

**Edit**

The update of the debug info shows where the problem is: `Host->h_addr` is NULL.  h_addr is actually a #define like this:

```
#define h_addr h_addr_list[0]
```

One of the functions is returning a `struct hostent` with an empty address list.

Comment: @DriverBoy:  I was right.  You are copying from a null pointer.

Comment: @compile-fan: `Host->h_addr` is null, you can see from his GDB output.  That means the memcpy will seg fault (as it does).

Comment: @DriverBoy: Because `Host->h_addr_list[0]` is NULL as shown by your GDB output and `Host->h_addr_list[0]` *is the same thing as* `Host->h_addr`

Comment: @DriverBoy: If you are asking what causes `Host->h_addr_list[0]` to be null in the first place, it's most likely because no IP addresses were found for the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, source and destination memory areas overlap? i.e.

```
&Result->sin_addr >= Host->h_addr >= &Result->sin_addr + sizeof(Result->sin_addr)
```

Comment: @DriverBoy, what is it equal to then?

Comment: `{h_name = 0xc4ee048 "", h_aliases = 0xc4ee030, h_addrtype = 2, h_length = 4, h_addr_list = 0xc4ee038}` as provided in my question.

Comment: @DriverBoy, @vines: See my edited answer for why h_addr doesn't exist.  It's a **macro** that refers to `h_addr_list[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The memcpy is failing.

This could be caused by 
  (1) sin_addr and h_addr are not the same sizes or 
  (2) sin_addr is a pointer and you have not malloc'd memory for it.

Please provide the definition and initialisation of Result for more info.

Comment: I've updated the definition of `Result` in my original question above.